# Wind behavior and pattern

Tags: structures, aerodynamics, wind-tunnels

From the 5 options, which one shows the worse wind effect? Is it (b) because wind speeds accelerate through a gap? But how about in comparison to (c)? Or (d) due to the height and sharp corners?

If it's (b), does building shape matter? Meaning, what if it's two square/rectangular building with a connecting bridge (without the splay or funneling of wind)?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: What do your notes and theory covered suggest?

Comment: worse effect in what manner? More turbulence? Increased drag? Disruption of airflow?

Comment: Increased wind speed and turbulence.